# Oracle Unknown Command - CONSTRAINT

Tags: oracle

I've decided to completely put out the SQL file here.

```
CREATE TABLE Account
(
    AccountNumber INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ADDR START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE Address
(
    AddressNumber INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AccountNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
    IsPrimary INTEGER NOT NULL,
    StreetName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ZipCode INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Bill
(
    AccountNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL,
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
    DueDate DATE NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT BillFK FOREIGN KEY (AccountNumber) REFERENCES Account(AccountNumber),
    CONSTRAINT BillPK PRIMARY KEY (AccountNumber, EndDate)
);
```

Again, the error I'm getting begins with the first Constraint call (unknown command beginning "CONSTRAINT..." - rest of line ignored.).  I'm also occasionally getting an 'unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored.'  Any ideas?

Comment: int is not a valid datatype in Oracle. Try changing it to Number or Integer

Comment: I created a test table `create table account(accountnumber int primary key);` and your table creates just fine in my environment (11.2.0.3). Are you sure it isn't a copy/paste error? Are you typing this into sqlplus?

Comment: I'm loading the file above into SQLPlus, yes.  I've decided to add the entirety of the file as it seems my issue isn't isolated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any empty lines will stop `SQL*Plus` from accepting the inputs blocks and put it in buffer.
So, when you started your `CONSTRAINT` keyword after an empty line, it treated it as a new command, and thrown an error.

Try this, before you run all your `DDLs`.

```
set sqlblanklines on
```

You need to instruct the sql*plus to ignore empty lines